# uml 2.0 sequence diagram: is a reply message obligatory when modeling a synchronous message

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

i have found some articles on uml sequence diagrams, which mention a reply message would be optionally, but i could not find any hint to confirm this in the 2.2 uml super structure specification. maybe someone who is familiar with that spec could answer the question and give me a hint in which part of the uml superstructure documentation i could find a definitive answer on this question.

thanks a lot in advance.

thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like it is in fact optional.

From Pg. 495 (pdf page 511) of the pdf at [OMG v 2.2 Superstructure](http://www.omg.org/cgi-bin/doc?formal/09-02-03):

> If the Message represents a CallAction, there will normally be a reply message from the called Lifeline back to the calling
>   lifeline before the calling Lifeline will proceed.

Here again, they use the text *normally* hinting that it's not required at all.

Answer (score 2):

If the message is synchronous, the expected behavior is that calling process will wait for the reply mesaage.
The decision to **show** it in the diagram may be optional, although diagram would become confusing.